# Flutter - Issue with callback function

Tags: dart, flutter

I've searched everywhere and can't find a simple solution. I'm new to coding and new to Flutter/Dart.

I suspect this is a very basic problem. I need to pass a callback via an intermediary widget to the final widget.

Overview of the issue:

`RootPage` > `TabNavigator` > `SearchPage` > `ProfilePage`(with logout button on `ProfilePage`). Does not work.

In `RootPage` the offending code is:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.notDetermined:
        return _buildWaitingScreen();
      case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
        return LoginPage(
          onSignedIn: _signedIn,
        );
      case AuthStatus.signedIn:
        return TabNavigation(
          ProfilePage(onSignedOut: _signedOut,)
        );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

`RootPage` > `SearchPage` (logout button on this `SearchPage`). Does work with this code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.notDetermined:
        return _buildWaitingScreen();
      case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
        return LoginPage(
          onSignedIn: _signedIn,
        );
      case AuthStatus.signedIn:
        return SearchPage(
          onSignedOut: _signedOut,
        );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Code snippet:

```
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  ProfilePage({this.onSignedOut});
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

 @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Manage Profile'),
            actions: <Widget> [
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text('Logout', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () => _signOut(context)
.....
....


class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  AuthStatus authStatus = AuthStatus.notDetermined;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.notDetermined:
        return _buildWaitingScreen();
      case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
        return LoginPage(
          onSignedIn: _signedIn,
        );
      case AuthStatus.signedIn:
        return TabNavigation(
          ProfilePage(onSignedOut: _signedOut), 
        );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Homepage of my app is `RootPage`, which manages the user's login status. Once logged in, the `RootPage` returns `TabNavigation`, which is a utility that manages the `bottomNavigationbar`, and returns `SearchPage` by default (i.e. `setState` returns `currentPage` = `SearchPage`).

I now wish to have the logout button on `ProfilePage`.

I don't know how to get the `onPressed` callback function to pass it's output back to `RootPage`.

Difficult to explain without pasting in the full code, but I hope you get the concept.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: No, no errors in the console

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [InheritedWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) at root level i.e. at _RootPageState class. Now you can pass any information(data) down at any point in hierarchy. In your case passed onPressed will get use at ProfilePage.

```
class LogoutAction extends InheritedWidget {
  const LogoutAction({
    Key key,
    @required this.logoutButtonClick,
    @required Widget child,
  }) : assert(logoutButtonClick != null),
       assert(child != null),
       super(key: key, child: child);

  final VoidCallback logoutButtonClick;

  static LogoutAction of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(LogoutAction);
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(LogoutAction old) => logoutButtonClick != old.logoutButtonClick;
}
```

now this LogoutAction widget can be used at

```
class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  AuthStatus authStatus = AuthStatus.notDetermined;

  _logoutClick() {
    //your code
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LogoutAction(
      logoutButtonClick: _logoutClick,
      child: //todo: child widget that will use ProfilePage
    );
  }
}
```

and your logout button will look like:

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: LogoutAction.of(context).logoutButtonClick
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is working in `SearchPage`, then it should be straightforward. Refer the below code,

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

  SearchPage(this.onSignedOut); //getting from RootPage (might be via TabNavigator)

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _SearchPage();
  }

}

class _SearchPage extends State<SearchPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var route = MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ProfilePage(this.widget.onSignedOut)); // sending the callback to ProfilePage
    Navigator.push(context, route);
  }
}

class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  ProfilePage(this.onSignedOut);
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Manage Profile'),
    actions: <Widget> [
    new FlatButton(
    child: new Text('Logout', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
    onPressed: () => onSignedOut() //invoking the callback which will execute in RootPage
    //....
  }
}
```

Note: In your `ProfilePage`, onPressed method name looks wrong `_signOut(context)`. If you are using some private method which calls `onSignedOut` that is fine. If not, you have to use `onSignedOut()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. This doesn't solve my problem. I've rewritten the question with additional detail and code snippets.